# About Intersection of two convex polytope?

Tags: matlab, algorithms, convex-optimization, geometry

the intersection of two convex hull of two polytope P and Q , is it the convex hull of the intersection of P&Q ? Conv(P) ∩ Conv(Q) = conv(P∩Q) ???.

Comment: I presume you are talking about non-convex polytopes. Have you tried some simple pen-and-paper drawing? Let one of the polytopes look like a "C" and one like "-". Now move the second towards the first and keep track of the convex hulls...

Answer (score 0):

[Convex polytopes, Branko Grünbaum](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387004242)

> 1. If $\{K_{v}\}$ is any (finite, or infinite, denumerable or not) family of convex sets in $R^{d}$, then their intersection $\bigcap\limits_{v} K_{v}$ is also convex.